# How can I make 3 bytes corresponding to RGB into a single byte?

Tags: vb.net, assembly

I'm making a 16 bit assembly program and the graphics mode I'm working only supports 256 colors per pixel that are written in a single byte. In other words, I can only specify one byte color value to draw a pixel. I converted an image into 8 bit depth bitmap and now I'm trying to take each pixel color value with Visual Basic so I can use those values in the assembly program but I'm getting a RGB value and when I try to convert those RGB values into a single byte I get numbers bigger than 256 so I can't use that in graphic mode. Here is what I have:

```
Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap("images.bmp")
Dim output As New System.IO.StreamWriter("colors.txt", False)
Dim pixelColor As Color
Dim rgb As Integer

For x As Integer = 1 To myBitmap.Width - 1 Step 1
            pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y)
            rgb = CUInt(pixelColor.B) + CUInt((pixelColor.G << 8)) + CUInt((pixelColor.R << 16))
            output.WriteLine(rgb.ToString)

        Next x

    Next y
output.Close()
```

The line that is actually giving me values higher than 256 is:

```
rgb = CUInt(pixelColor.B) + CUInt((pixelColor.G << 8)) + CUInt((pixelColor.R << 16))
```

Is there actually any way to convert, merge or approximate the 3 RGB values altogether into a single byte? (which can't be more than 255)

---

---

EDIT:
Since we are already into the VB net stuff let me write the working line of code with the conversion logic **David** wrote:

```
rgb = ((pixelColor.R / 32) << 5) + ((pixelColor.G / 32) << 2) + (pixelColor.B / 64)
```

Thanks David.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 3 bits for the red value, 3 for green, and 2 for blue. It's explained well on the Wikipedia page about [8-bit color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color).

The conversion logic is:

```
[(Red / 32) << 5] + [(Green / 32) << 2] + (Blue / 64)
```

Comment: Such a quick answer makes me look bad. Been hours on this and that's how it was done. Hehe. Thanks. :)