# Single Byte to RGB and RGB to Single Byte

Tags: c#

I'm creating a retro emulator and cannot remember for the life of me how to convert a **single byte** into an RGB value and back from RGB into a single byte.

I've tried using bitwise methods but it just doesn't seem to work for this scenario.

I have found this post that is similar, [How can I make 3 bytes corresponding to RGB into a single byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222992/how-can-i-make-3-bytes-corresponding-to-rgb-into-a-single-byte), however I just can't get it to work as the values returned are greater than 255.

So for understanding, if anyone used to have an Atari ST or ZX Spectrum the colour pallet was very compact which could fit into one byte and not like todays 4 byte rgba.

Can anyone jog my memory?

Pseudocode

```
int R = 1 (range 0 to 6); 
int G = 3 (range 0 to 6); 
int B = 5 (range 0 to 6);

// Convert values to single byte
byte myByte = (R << 2) + (G << 1) + (B)

// Convert byte back to RGB
R = myByte / ?; 
G = myByte / ?;
B = myByte / ?
```

Comment: Does the maximum value of 6 in this situation indicates maximum color intensity?

Comment: 3 bits per channel, 3 channels --> 9 Bit. How is that supposed to fit in 1 Byte? Also R, G and B will overlap because they are only shiftet 1 bit each. That code doesn't work. If you want to fit a color into a single Byte, you need to use a Palette (like GIFs do for example) or sacrifice one bit (preferably not green) like in the question you linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make 3 bytes corresponding to RGB into a single byte?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222992/how-can-i-make-3-bytes-corresponding-to-rgb-into-a-single-byte)

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit: http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Atari_ST_color_palette

Comment: I don't think there is any general direct conversion as the Atari and Sinclair seem to have very different 8-bit color palettes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_8-bit_computer_hardware_palettes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the conversion algorithm given on linked answer

```
rgb8 = [(Red / 32) << 5] + [(Green / 32) << 2] + (Blue / 64)
```

Now to get RGB

```
byte R = (byte) ((rgb8 & 0xE0) >> 5);     // rgb8 & 1110 0000  >> 5
byte G = (byte) ((rgb8 & 0x1C) >> 2);     // rgb8 & 0001 1100  >> 2
byte B = (byte) (rgb8 & 0x03);            // rgb8 & 0000 0011
```

And to pack it in one byte again

```
byte RGB = (byte)((R << 5) | (G << 2) | B);
```

Comment: @Overdrive77 is there any problem there?

Comment: Just can't get that method to work as it's returning 0? The method posted is based on modern r 255, g 255 and b 255